# symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: undefined symbol: xkb_state_key_get_utf8

Tags: qt4.7, qt5.3, migrating, qkeyevent

while migrating my application from Qt4.7 to qt5.3 
 i made all the changes needed in the code according to qt5

my applications started but when i tried to login.. the application closed and it did not crashed rather

it stoped with this error

```
   /home/tender/Documents/Smartlottoqt5/Smartlottoqt5: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64        /qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: undefined symbol: xkb_state_key_get_utf8
```

initially i thought that application is crashing so tried to use debugger but that is not the case.

i think its somthing realted to Qkeyevent because the application stops when i pressed any key, and i have overloaded eventfilter in my code and i am handing Qkeyevents.

kindly guide me through this error!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same problem on Fedora 20 with Qt5 from repo. I updated libxkbcommon it solved this.
Try to update libxkbcommon.